# LEN function not returning a value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

With the following code segment the Strings.Len() function is being skipped or not returning a value since the debugger says the variable Test1 is not assigned while the following line with Strings.InStr() function works properly:

```
   sOPCTagItem = opcTagItem.Cells.Value --> assigns "DO1001_Inp_IOFault"    
   sBaseTagItemName = Left(sOPCTagItem, InStr(sOPCTagItem, "_") - 1) --> assigns "DO1001"

   iTest1 = Len(sOPCTagItem)  --> = nothing assigned
   iTest2 = InStr(sOPCTagItem, "_") --> = 7
   iTest1 = iTest1 - iTest2   --> = nothing assigned
   sBaseTagItemExtension = Right(sOPCTagItem, Len(sOPCTagItem) - InStr    (sOPCTagItem, "_"))   --> = nothing assigned
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.Length` and `.Split` in place of len left and right?

Comment: Do you have a `Function Len(s As String) As [Not the Right Type]` somewhere? It would override the standard one. Or is `iTest1` *something* that actually doesn't like Integers? What is it? Could you post the Type of those variables/fields and how they're declared?

Comment: Thanks Jimi,  yes the Len function is overloaded (+15) and I used (s As String).  iTest1 & ITest2 at dimensioned as Integer

Comment: Thanks Andrew, .Length worked but I now see the issue is not the functions Len or .Length, but the variable names Test1, & sBaseTagItemExtension.  Apparently as I watch the variables they are flagged as error BC30451: 'iTest1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   When I changed iTest1 assignment to iTest2 = Len(sOPCTagItem) it worked.  My issue is that all variables are DIM'd as either String or Integer, so I don't know what the issue is asking me to correct.

Comment: @CC If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) then Visual Studio can show you where there are problems with the types of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these methods work for your scenario.
They will depend on your input data and the consistency of underscore delimiters in your data.

You may just be missing `Option Explicit On`

```
Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    Debug.Print(getBaseTagItem("DO1001_Inp_IOFault"))
    Debug.Print(getBaseTagItemOldSchool("DO1001_Inp_IOFault"))
End Sub

Private Function getBaseTagItem(tagItem As String)

    Dim vals() As String = tagItem.Split("_"c)
    Return String.Concat(vals(1), "_", vals(2))

End Function

Private Function getBaseTagItemOldSchool(tagItem As String)

    Dim sOPCTagItem As String = tagItem
    Dim sBaseTagItemName As String = Strings.Left(sOPCTagItem, InStr(sOPCTagItem, "_") - 1)

    Dim iTest1 As Integer = Len(sOPCTagItem)
    Dim iTest2 As Integer = InStr(sOPCTagItem, "_")
    iTest1 = iTest1 - iTest2
    Dim sBaseTagItemExtension As String = Strings.Right(sOPCTagItem, Len(sOPCTagItem) - InStr(sOPCTagItem, "_"))
    Return sBaseTagItemExtension

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks to all - the "Option Strict On" worked.  Issue was not related to functions, but to DIM block where I was assigning values along with DIM assignments.  When I fixed the 2 variables in the Watch list were now pre-assigned as "Nothing"

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that they return nothing since their return value is an integer. I would try using the proper String method.

```
    iTest1 = sOPCTagItem.Length
    iTest2 = sOPCTagItem.IndexOf("_")
    iTest1 = iTest1 - iTest2
    sBaseTagItemExtension = sOPCTagItem.Substring(sOPCTagItem.Length - sOPCTagItem.IndexOf("_"))
```